# Sending POST through function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to send POST request if validation passes. But it doesn't. Can someone show me a wway to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function go()
    {
    var username = document.form.name.value;
    var pwd = document.form.pwd.value;
    if (username == '') {
      var oldHTML = document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="Please fill out username.";
    var newHTML = "<span style='color:red'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
    if (pwd == '') {
      var oldHTML = document.getElementById('myAnchor2').innerHTML="Please fill out password.";
    var newHTML = "<span style='color:red'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
    document.getElementById('myAnchor2').innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
      else {
       document.form.method="POST";
       document.form.action = "data.php";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks correct, you just need to actually submit the form. Add the following line into your `else` block like this:

```
else {
    document.form.method="POST";
    document.form.action = "data.php";
    //submit the form -- new line is below
    document.form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

below is snippet how to submit form via javascript

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```